# Redshift stored procedure - Add single quoted value in a variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I want to pass a value from the parameter inside the single quote. It's actually for RedShift.

Basically, I want to generate this below query.

```sql
unload ('select * from bhuvi') 
to 's3://bhuvi-bucket/folder//user-data.csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/myredshiftrole' 
delimiter '|'  GZIP";
```

#### My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_variable()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
   sql text;
   s3_loc text;
   role text;
   deli text;
   query text
BEGIN
   sql:='select * from bhuvi';
   s3_loc:='s3://bhuvi-bucket/folder/'
   role:='arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/myredshiftrole'
   deli:='|'
   query := "unload (sql) to 's3_loc/user-data.csv' iam_role 'role' delimiter deli GZIP";
   execute query;
END
$$;
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you please clarify your question? What are you wanting to do, what have you tried and what error/problem are you having? What do you mean by " a value from the parameter inside the single quote"? Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: What I want us, I want to generate the unload command (1st snippet) from stored procedure. So in future I can use this procedure to get values from parameters

Comment: When I run this procedure I got error at like one

Answer (score 0):

You can join strings using `||` like this:

```sql
f2 := f2 || '+' || f2;
```

(From [Overview of Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html))