# Can't declare variable in Redshift UDF

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

hi I'm unable to create this function, it throws me an error "syntax error near int". I'm using redshift

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stage.calc_enddate( int, int, timestamp)
    RETURNS timestamp
    LANGUAGE sql
    STABLE
AS $$
declare
 p int := 0;
begin 
    if ($1 >1) then
        select $3       
    end if
end
    
$$;
```

thanks in advance
Sundar

Comment: I think that `int` shouldn't be there. For some examples, see: [Redshift stored procedure - Add single quoted value in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57655621/174777)

Answer (score 0):

According to Amazon Redshift's guide to the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html)

[Data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html)

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stage.calc_enddate(INT, INT, TIMESTAMP)
        RETURNS TIMESTAMP
    stable
    AS $$
    begin 
        if ($1 >1) then
            select $3       
        end if
    end
        
    $$ language sql;
```

Comment: same error, it is not working. thanks for the anser

Comment: Please try again.

Comment: same error after trying it again

Comment: First, remove "declare p INT := 0;"

Comment: I need to declare that variable because im going to use it, any other way to declare the variable?

Comment: Refer to the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46118135/19538002